# Get first item of every sublist of list in Python

Tags: python, arraylist

I have the following string which is a list of lists:

```
"ID":[[310.5,1.1612828],[310.0,15.0],[310.0,2.9755309],[309.5,30.0]]
```

I want to grab all the first values of each list into a `variable`, so the output should be in this case

```
print variable
```

expected output:

```
310.5
310.0
310.0
309.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the first elements into a variable, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

#### Code:

```
data = {
    'ID': [[310.5, 1.1612828],
           [310.0, 15.0],
           [310.0, 2.9755309],
           [309.5, 30.0]]
}

variable = [x[0] for x in data['ID']]

print(variable)
```

#### Results:

```
[310.5, 310.0, 310.0, 309.5]
```

Comment: I really like this answer but it doesn't work in my scenario..I neglected to say this lists of lists is nested inside a dictionary like this {a="timestamp":1496485492,"ID":[[310.5,1.1612828],[310.0,15.‌​0],[310.0,2.9755309]‌​,[309.5,30.0]]} can you help?

Comment: The answer supplied fits that scenario exactly.  Just change `data` to match the name of your dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

```
id = [[310.5,1.1612828],[310.0,15.0],[310.0,2.9755309],[309.5,30.0]]

# If you just want to output to console:
[print(x[0]) for x in id]  #if id a list
# if id is in dict named dict_
[print(x[0] for x in dict_['id']
```

Here's a longer version.

```
dict_ = {'id': [[310.5,1.1612828],
                [310.0,15.0],
                [310.0,2.9755309],
                [309.5,30.0]]
                }



#make a list containing position 0 values of sublists
pos_0 = [x[0] for x in dict_['id']]
print(pos_0)

#output them to a file
for entry in pos_0:
      print(entry)
```

Comment: Thanks for the above but this seems to give me a print out of [[310.5,1.1612828],[310.0,15.0],[310.0,2.9755309],[309.5,30.0]] with the second element still present..

Comment: While you _could_ do this, it's not idiomatic to use a list comprehension only for its side effects. The better way is to split this into to separate steps. First create the list, then print it.

Comment: I know I was just showing it as a proof of concept for how to do it. Below is a more verbose edition.

Comment: could this be because the list of lists is nested inside a dictionary? so the full "list"looks like this {a="timestamp":1496485492,"ID":[[310.5,1.1612828],[310.0,15.0],[310.0,2.9755309],[309.5,30.0]]}

Answer (score 0):

This code will iterate over every first element and append it to the out list for ease of access in the future.

```
dict_ = {"ID":[[310.5,1.1612828],[310.0,15.0],[310.0,2.9755309],[309.5,30.0]]}
out=[]

for item in dict_["ID"]:
    out.append(item[0])
print(out)
```

This will output `[310.5, 310.0, 310.0, 309.5]`. Is this what you needed?